# Print numeric values to two decimal places

Tags: php, formatting, decimal

I'm using a simple loop to echo back some numbers.

```
<?php
$inc = 0.25;
$start =  0.25;
$stop = 5.00;
?>
        
<?php while($start != ($stop + $inc)){ ?>
<option><?php echo $start ?></option>
<?php $start = $start + $inc; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

However `5.00` appears as `5` and `4.50` appears as `4.5`.

How would I get this script to display `5.00`, `4.00`, `3.00`, `3.50`?

Comment: You might also have a bug where your loop does not terminate because of floating point numbers not being exact instead use 
while ($start <= ($stop+($inc/2)) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

```
printf("%01.2f", $start)
```

or if you need to store it to variable

```
$var = sprintf("%01.2f", $start)
```

You can also use number_format, this is good when you need to format that in some country formatting rules. You can provide decimal and thousand separator

```
number_format($start, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

There also is number_format that lets you choose the thousand and decimal separators: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `printf()` for formatted strings:

```
printf("%01.2f", $start)
```

The full manual for (s)printf can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php while($start != ($stop + $inc)){ ?>
<option><?php printf('%01.2f', $start) ?></option>
<?php $start = $start + $inc; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price1 = 6.67; $price2 = 5.55; $total = $price1 + $price2;
echo $total;
echo "\n";
//the . means dot position, 4 means 4 digits after the .
$result= sprint("%0.4f", $total); 
echo $result;
outputs: 12.22 12.2200
```

f means float (maybe obvious maybe not:) can try above code by changing the number after the . to get whatever number of digits you want.